# How to vertically place Plotly Dash Navbar on the left in python?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python, dash-bootstrap-components

I am trying to replicate the Navbar on the left side in the following link:

- https://historicalbaseball.herokuapp.com/team

I have tried this so far and I've looked through the other example projects provided by Plotly and Dash and nothing else looks similar:

```py
import os
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

app_name = os.getenv("DASH_APP_PATH", "/dash-baseball-statistics")

# Navigation Bar function
def Navbar():
    navbar = dbc.NavbarSimple(
        children=[
            dbc.NavItem(dbc.NavLink("Team Analysis", href=f"{app_name}/team")),
            dbc.NavItem(dbc.NavLink("Batting Analysis", href=f"{app_name}/player")),
            dbc.NavItem(
                dbc.NavLink("Pitching/Fielding Analysis", href=f"{app_name}/field")
            ),
        ],
        brand="Home",
        brand_href=f"{app_name}",
        sticky="top",
        color="light",
        dark=False,
        expand="lg",
    )
    return navbar
```

The code is from the Plotly Dash example below, however the Navbar seems to be fixed horizontally at the top of the page when the code is run, like the following image:
[image: Horizontal Navbar]

https://github.com/plotly/dash-sample-apps/blob/main/apps/dash-baseball-statistics/navbar.py

How can the following vertical `Navbar` be achieved using Plotly Dash?

[image: Vertical Navbar]

Comment: @Ouroborus I've looked through the docs, 
https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/navbar/

No info about a vertical bar there. I've gone through all the other example dashboards and nothing is similar, hence the reason for the question.

Comment: `NavBar` appears to only support placement at the top or bottom. Dash doesn't seem to have the ability to create a sidebar at the page level. You'll likely need to use a native layout (`dcb.Div`s with custom styling, in this case) to split the view into sidebar and content. Then place a `Nav` in the sidebar and content in the content area.

Comment: May be this one can help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ln8dyS2y4Nc&t=987s